# PHP/JS Result if my position is between 2 coordinates

Tags: javascript, php, geolocation, position, coordinates

I have some coordinates for example:

A-15.555, 25.6565
B-15.631, 25.9565
C-16.585, 26.2435
...

I want to make a script using my location (by mobile phone).
If my location is in a radius of 500 meters of each position, it will show something as "You're between the position A and B".

So if I'm in the location 15.604, 25.7521, I'm between the A and B positions and the script will tell me that.

I don't know how to do because I'm not expert of the geolocation scripts.

Thanks so much!

--------------------EDIT---------------------

--------------------UPDATE---------------------

Maybe it should be simple in this way:

-I obtain the user's location using the PHP Geolocation.

-I need to make a PHP script to search for the two nearest position based on the user's location

-Display these two position

Is it possible?

Comment: All you need is a simple 2D distance formula.

Comment: Thanks @JCode but I'm not understanding

Answer (score 0):

One solution (not sure if it's what you're looking for) is to measure the distance between your location and the specified points. So you could say something like this:

```
if (pointA.distance(MyLocation) < 500 distance_units && pointB.distance(MyLocation) < 
   500 distance_units) {
    notify_user
}
```

Not sure which programming language you're using, but maybe there are some handy labraries you could use that already have such functions. Otherwise you should make a method to gives you the distance between one geo location and another.

Hope this helps. Have a good night!

Comment: Thank you but it's not what I need.
I want to use PHP in order to show something if the user's location in a radius of two positions.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a vincenty formula. It will allow you to calculate the distance between two sets of coordinates. [Movable Type](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-vincenty.html) has JavaScript source code to do so, and it returns the distance in meters. Just remember, that the author extended the JavaScript number object with toRadians() and toDegrees() methods.  You will have to do the same.  I've used this code previously in a production app and it works well.

Comment: Thank you but it's not what I need.
I want to use PHP in order to show something if the user's location in a radius of two positions.